# Json dump to separate variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have view:

```
def hero(request):
  rfc='some value'
  depends_on=1234
  result_set = {'rfc': rfc, 'depends_on': depends_on}
  return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result_set))
```

Now in template i want in two js variable one with rfc vaue and another with depends_on value .SO that i can use those variables to populate some fields.  How is it possible .

kindly help.

Comment: Please include more detail about what you want to achieve? Do you want to pass this context to templates ?

Comment: @RajaSimon context is already passed to template as result_set . now i want to acces those two key rfc and depends_on in the js script

Comment: @ilak If you are passing value as context and you have nothing to do with asynchronous request, then why **ajax** tag?

Comment: becouse  i am using ajax call to call the hero function as the return the hero function is returning json.dumps which i want to acces as key and value in template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying ajax, then you can do it like -

```
<script>
   var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET","your_hero_url",true);
   xhr.onreadtstatechange=function(){
      if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
         var result_set=JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         console.log(result_set["key"]);
      }
   }
   xhr.send(null);
</script>
```

And also in your views you can modify -

```
def hero(request):
   result_set = {"key": "value"}
   return JsonResponse(result_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Django context in Javascript using the Django template tag.

```
const result_set = JSON.parse('{{ result_set|escapejs }}')
```

Comment: I think it would be better to use `{{ result_set }}` within quotes i.e.` const result_set = "{{ result_set }}";`.

Comment: how i will aces  the keys and values in js